# Bootstrap 3.0 Modal Code in a separate file

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have a common modal that would be invoked from various places in different forms. I'm trying to write a common code for it in a separate file and invoke it. If code for Modal is included in the same file as button invoking it, it works fine. But if I place code for Modal form in a separate file, it doesn't open Modal form.

Here is the code of button invoking Modal form:

```
<a href="modal.html#myModal" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-toggle="modal">Edit</a>
```

Here is the code of Modal Form in a different HTML file, "Modal.html":

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Club Search Result</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p id="dispMsg">   </p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Search Again</button>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Comment: This got resolved by adding following script :

Comment: <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#ModalCode").load("addressModal.html #myModal");
    });

</script>

Comment: why not write a full answer to this and explain the details? e.g. what is the #ModalCode you refer to? (not mentioned in OP).